# Altair-viz repeat and transform

Tags: python, altair

Is there a way to apply a data transform or filter using the encoding used by a repeated chart?

If I understand correctly the [docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/compound_charts.html#repeated-charts), it appears it is not directly possible:

> Currently repeat can only be specified for rows and column (not, e.g., for layers) and the target can only be encodings (not, e.g., data transforms) but there is discussion within the Vega-Lite community about making this pattern more general in the future.

What would be good ways to work around this? For instance below, say I want to plot only the points for which `y>0` (or could be another transform, I don't want to just zoom on the y axis). Is there a way to apply something like the line #0 using the repeat target (as attempted in #1, which fails with `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'RepeatRef' and 'float'`)?

```py
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.arange(100)
source = pd.DataFrame({
  'x': x,
  'f': np.sin(x / 5),
  'g': np.cos(x / 3),    
})

alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    alt.X('x', type='quantitative'),
    alt.Y(alt.repeat('column'), type='quantitative'),
).transform_filter(
    # alt.datum.f >= 0. #0 Works, but would like to use f or g depending on the plotted variable
    alt.repeat('column') > 0. #1 ERROR HERE
).repeat(
    column=['f', 'g']
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to reference the repeated field within a transform. The best way to approach this would be to build the chart via concatenation; for example:

```
alt.hconcat(*(
  alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
      alt.X('x', type='quantitative'),
      alt.Y(col, type='quantitative'),
  ).transform_filter(
      alt.datum[col] >= 0
  ) 
  for col in ['f', 'g']
))
```

[image]